# EF Core Sum on Enum

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have a UserVote table that is based on the following domain object:

```
public class UserVote {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public Guid PostId {get;set;}
    public Guid UserId {get;set;}
    public VoteType VoteType {get;set;}
}

public enum VoteType {
    Upvote = 1,
    Downvote = 0
}
```

How can I write a query to get the total count of VoteType for unique PostId's?

I've tried grouping by PostId and then calling `Count` but it didn't work:

```
_ctx.UserVotes.Where(x=>x.PostId == PostId).GroupBy(x=>x.PostId).Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. I needed to cast the `enum` to an `int`

`_ctx.Where(x => x.PostId == PostId).Sum(x => (int)x.VoteType);`

Comment: Your Downvote value is 0 . Sum returns 0 for any count of votes .

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
_ctx.UserVotes.Count(x=> x.PostId == PostId && x.VoteType == VoteType.Up);
```

Comment: This won't work because I need to sum by the VoteType enum